# Best caching techniques for rest API using spring boot

Tags: rest, caching, spring-boot

Could anyone please help me to use the best caching techniques for REST API's using spring boot. Reason looking for caching is, when database goes down we should be able to retrieve the details from cache for few API's.

Comment: What do you mean by cache in case of unavailable DB? A copy of the database?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by cache in case of unavailable DB? - When DB requires downtime, if user request for data, we should be able to fetch the details from cache. 2) A copy of the database? - Not everything, only few transactions and its kind of static response

Comment: It sounds that you want to store partial data in cache and directly return it as response while DB is unavailable? If yes, then I don't think this scenario has high dependency to Spring Framework, any caching mechanism such as Google - Guava Cache can achieve your requirement.

Comment: I can see Guava is mentioned as deprecated in this link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html